# Ionic 3 - call method defined in .ts from downloaded innerHtml

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I write app to display latest posts from one portal.

I **download the content** and display it in html template via **[innerHtml]**.
Some posts may contain galleries that I'd like to show with **Modal Page** that has a slider.

My html template

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div [innerHtml]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(pageContent)" >
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

How can I call function to open Modal (defined in post.ts) from downloaded html?
I sanitize the html so my code isn't removed, but normal Ionic methods like (click)="openModal()" don't work.

My downloaded html:

```
<button (click)="openModal()">Show gallery</button>
```

Maybe some javascript onclick="openModal()" ? But then I get openModal is not defined.